# Реализация авторизации на сайте, применяя сессию

Tags: php, сессия

Как лучше реализовать авторизацию на сайте, использую id сессии...

На сайте возможно авторизоваться на нескольких устройствах и при необходимости выйти со всех устройств.

Как это выполнено в данный момент:

- Авторизовываясь, генерирую уникальный ключ, затем в отдельно поле у пользователя в бд. Заношу его, так при каждой авторизации. Сохраняю только последние 3 ключа. Если пользователю необходимо разлогиниться, просто удаляем необходимой ключ из поля и обновляем.
- Имея в куках сгенерированный ключ, выполняем поиск в таблице применяя

  `session` LIKE '%,{$hashi},%'"

Сделано ненадежно, но маловероятно, что ключ при авторизации будет выдан дважды. Для этого к каждому ключу в начале, добавляю id пользователя.

Ненадежно, почему?
При желании если разобраться, то вполне возможно понять, что в начале каждого ключа присутствует id пользователя. Остается просто рандомно, миллион и миллион раз генерировать ключи чтобы попасть в необходимый аккаунт. А если каким то образом просмотреть логику формировния ключа, то чтобы взломать чей то аккаунт не составит труда.

**Возвращаясь к вопросу о применении id сессии в качестве ключа.**

Не совсем понятно как и каким образом лучше поступить. Было бы плевым делом, если при авторизации заносить в переменную сессии id пользователя, а затем брать id и данные из бд.
Все отлично, на вид, это гораздо надежнее будет чем принцип описанный выше. И поиск в бд по числу, а не по строчке, что скорость работы значительно выше.

Но остается вопрос, как в таком случаи реализовать выход из аккаунта на всех устройствах?

Или остается только выносить все id сессий и id пользователей которым присваивается сессия? В таком случаи при выборке придется делать запрос через left в 2 таблицы. И обновлять тайм сессии, скажем каждые 5 часов, всего сессия храниться неделю. Чтобы не вылетала авторизация если пользователь был активен скажем 2 суток назад.
Так же обновлять тайм в таблице сессиий и выставлять крон для удаления строк, тайм обновления которых более недели назад.

Первый вариант выглядит лучше и надежней, со вторым много головной боли.

Возможно как то лучше, возможно есть еще вариант для реализации данного функционала?

Или если пользователь выходит со всех устройств, брать все сессии их скажем миллион. Открывать, читать и если в сессии id пользователя соответствует, удаляем. Конечно просто, но какая будет нагрузка и как долго этот процесс займет.

Comment: Смешались в кучу кони, люди.... :)
1) ***никогда*** не делайте в качестве идентификатора сессии - айди пользователя из БД, тем более числовой(хотя способ есть, надо только глянуть документацию по пхп и\или http)
2) У вас какая нагрузка на сайт что вы хотите хранить вместо стандартного идентификатора айдишник( ?
3) сессия никак не связана с длительным хранением авторизации, для этого используется более длинный токен, желательно в связке с айпи или иным указателем который для вас приемлем.

Comment: Сессия пользователя храниться неделю. В firefox невозможно сохранять тот же куки который был ранее удален. ID пользователя не храню в качестве индетификатора, но в качестве исключения его можно сохранить в переменной сессии, на сервере, на стороне пользователя будет храниться ключ сессии. Если пользователь заходит на сайт, открывается его файл сессии и достается id пользователя из сессии. Другие пользователи никак не смогу получить его если не будут знать ключ сессии.

Comment: Чем плох способ, если хранить id пользователя в переменной сессии? По мне только лучше будет, не нужно брать ключ из куков, парсить его от различных инъекций и выборку делать по числу, а не по строчке.

Comment: Хранить id пользователя в сессии - норм практика(так по сути и нужно делать в общем случае). Все ваши проблемы решаются просто переносом хранилища сессий из ФС в БД(получаем пару проблем и кучу бонусов) :) 
Далее у вас большое заблуждение что поиск индексированных строк - дольше чем поиск числа:) на грани погрешности а иногда и быстрей засчет бинарных деревьев и нормального распределения хорошей хеш функцией :)
Конечно если использовать и дальше запросы вида like %{text}% - скорость будет падать :) если интересно понять - давайте в чат, там проще обьяснить

Comment: Плохо не id хранить в сессии а использовать id пользователя в качестве токена сессии :) в пхп можно самостоятельно рулить токеном сессии, я подумал вы туда хотите загнать id пользователя

Comment: Хорошо. Сессия храниться 5 дней, если пользователь заходит на 3 день, время ее хранения не изменяется. То есть зайдя на сайт, через 3 суток. Сессия по-прежнему будет удалена через 2 суток, так как была создана 3 суток ранее? Не совсем понятен параметр `cookie_lifetime`, как указать что необходимо установить новую дату удаления сессии. Чтобы через 2 суток у пользователя не слетела авторизация.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123557/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: Время жизни куки устанавливается(обновляется) при помощи заголовков или готовой функции со стороны сервера это например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php